# How to use mapcomplex in C#

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, mapping, linq-expressions

I am trying to map an object from my entity framework to an object. Everything was working fine until I had to do a list of objects. I get an error saying I should use a mapcomplex instead of a map. Unfortunately, I cannot find any doc on that function.

Complete classes:

```
using Cld.Domain.DataService.Contract.Filter;
using Cld.Domain.DataService.Contract.Model;
using Cld.Domain.DataService.Service.Model;
using Core.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Cld.Domain.DataService.Service.Repositories
{
    internal class ConditRepository : RepositoryBase<CONDIT, Condit, string>,
                                         ISearchableRepository<CONDIT, Condit, ConditFilter>
    {
         public static readonly IMapping<CONDIT, Condit> ConditMap = new Mapping<CONDIT, Condit>()
            .Maps(entity => entity.ID, contract => contract.Id)
            .Maps(entity => entity.LIBELLE_D, contract => contract.LabelD)
            .Maps(entity => entity.LIBELLE_E, contract => contract.LabelE)
            .Maps(entity => entity.LIBELLE_F, contract => contract.LabelF)
            .Maps(entity => entity.LIBELLE_N, contract => contract.LabelN)
            .Maps(entity => entity.TRACKURL, contract => contract.TrackUrl)
            .Maps(entity => entity.CODE, contract => contract.Code)
            .Maps(entity => entity.CUSTID, contract => contract.Custid)
            .Maps(entity => entity.NUMERO, contract => contract.Number)
            .Maps(entity => entity.SCAC, contract => contract.Scac)
            .Maps(entity => entity.SERVIID, contract => contract.ServiId)
            .Maps(entity => entity.SHIPORDER, contract => contract.ShipOrder)
            .Maps(entity => entity.REQTIME, contract => contract.RequestedDateTime)
            .Maps(entity => entity.OutputPath, contract => contract.OutputPath)
            .Maps(entity => entity.PACTYPs.Select(x => x.ID).ToList(), contract => contract.listPacktypes)
            ;
    }
}
```

then the class from the EF:

```
namespace Cld.Domain.DataService.Service.Model
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class CONDIT
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public CONDIT()
        {
            this.SHIPMENTs = new HashSet<SHIPMENT>();
            this.PACTYPs = new HashSet<PACTYP>();
        }

        public string LIBELLE_F { get; set; }
        public string LIBELLE_N { get; set; }
        public short NUMERO { get; set; }
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string LIBELLE_E { get; set; }
        public string LIBELLE_D { get; set; }
        public string CUSTID { get; set; }
        public string SERVIID { get; set; }
        public string SCAC { get; set; }
        public string CODE { get; set; }
        public string TRACKURL { get; set; }
        public int SHIPORDER { get; set; }
        public System.TimeSpan REQTIME { get; set; }
        public string OutputPath { get; set; }
        public byte[] timestamp_column { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<SHIPMENT> SHIPMENTs { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<PACTYP> PACTYPs { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And finally the contract I'm trying to fit it into:

```
using Cld.Core.ContractFramework;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace Cld.Domain.DataService.Contract.Model
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Condit : IEntity<string>
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string LabelF { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string LabelN { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string LabelE { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string LabelD { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public short Number { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public byte[] Timestamp { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Custid { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string ServiId { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Scac { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Code { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string TrackUrl { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public int ShipOrder { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public TimeSpan RequestedDateTime { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string OutputPath { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public List<int> listPacktypes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a tag for the mapper you're using.

Comment: I did not know there were multiple mappers. We're using the one from Linq.expression
I'm not the one that worked on it before, I just took after the other guy left (without doc, of course)

Comment: Then can you include a small, complete repro of the issue in your question?

Answer (score 0):

A colleague logged in and I managed to ask him the question.

Here's the result:

```
.MapComplex((entity, contractEntity, synchronizer) =>
            {
                contractEntity.listCondits = entity.CONDITs.Select(x => x.ID).ToList();

            });
```

entity automatically take the original type, contractEntity take the type you want to put the info into, and I don't know what the synchronizer is.
From there, you can manipulate them how you want. So in this case, I modified the contract entity by filling its listCondits with the info from the original entity.

Sorry for the trouble, my colleague was supposed to have left and not reconnect.